# Question about dual of dual of Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a real Hilbert space and let $H'$ be the set of continuous linear functionals on $H$.

Then, I know by the Riesz Theorem that for every $L(\cdot) \in H'$, there exists a unique $u\in H$ so that $(u,\cdot)_H = L(\cdot)$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)_H$ denotes the inner product on H. So, I can write $H' = \{(u,\cdot)_H: u\in H\}$

Now, my question is if I consider $(H')'$, the set of continuous linear functionals on $H'$, how does an element in $(H')'$ act on $H'$?

That is, if $f(\cdot) \in (H')'$, what is $f$ explicitly and also what is $f((u,\cdot)_H)$??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Riesz theorem gives the existence of an isometric isomorphism $\phi: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}^*$ such that
$f(x) = \langle \phi^{-1}(f), x \rangle $ for $f \in \mathbb{H}^*$. This
induces an inner product
$\langle f, g \rangle_{*} = \langle \phi^{-1}(f),\phi^{-1}(g)  \rangle$.

Since $\mathbb{H}^*$ is also a Hilbert space, the Riesz theorem gives the existence of an isometric isomorphism $\eta: \mathbb{H}^* \to \mathbb{H}^{**}$ such that
$J(f) = \langle \eta^{-1}(J), f \rangle_{{*}} $ for all $J\in \mathbb{H}^{**}$.

Then we have $J(f) = \langle \eta^{-1}(J), f \rangle_{{*}} = \langle f, \eta^{-1}(J) \rangle_{{*}} = \langle \phi^{-1}(f), \phi^{-1}(\eta^{-1}(J)) \rangle = f((\eta \circ \phi)^{-1}(J))$.

If we let $j= \phi^{-1}(\eta^{-1}(J) \in \mathbb{H}$, we can identify $J$ with $j$ by $J(f) = f(j)$.

Comment: So clear! I see it

Comment: @copper.hat: Doesn't one have to check as well that the induced inner product gives rise to the same norm: $\|\phi(x)\|':=\langle\phi(x),\phi(x)\rangle=\sup_z\langle\phi(x),\phi(z)\rangle=\sup_z\langle x,z\rangle=\|\langle x,\cdot\rangle\|=\|\phi(x)\|$

Comment: @Freeze_S: Indeed you do, it follows from the polarisation identity which relates the inner product and norms. (You have $\|f\|_* = \|\phi^{-1}(f)\|$.)

Comment: @cooper.hat : Can you elaborate on this please ? See my question here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1393655/dual-of-hilbert-space-induced-norm-vs-operator-norm?lq=1

Comment: @M.G: Elaborate on what?

Answer (score 0):

Given $f \in H'$ it's not really proper to write $f = \langle \cdot, u\rangle$ and say that this is a closed form solution for $f$ (where $u \in H$ is the unique element guaranteed by the Riesz theorem).  With that being said, the relationship between $H''$ and $H'$ is the same as that between $H'$ and $H$.  That is, given $F \in H''$ there is a unique $f \in H'$ where $F(g) = \langle g, f\rangle_{H'}$ for every $g \in H'$.  There really isn't a need to refer back to the elements in $H$ if you're talking about elements in $H''$ (although we do have the fact that $H$ is isometrically embedded in $H''$).

Comment: Why is it no propert to write  f=⟨⋅,u⟩?

Comment: Just pick $L^2[0,1]$ and try to expand the inner product.  You can't, it's not a closed-form expression for the functional.